# Add string to the first dimension on a two dimensional list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have created a two dimensional `List`. I want to add two different strings for both dimensions using a `for` loop. But the problem is that there is any option as `Add` for saving my string in the first dimension. May anyone could help?

```
        List<Tuple<int, List<string>>> List_type1 = new List<Tuple<int, List<string>>>();
        List<Tuple<int, List<string>>> List_type2 = new List<Tuple<int, List<string>>>();            
        int indx1;
        int indx2;
        List<TreeNode> IndexList1 = new List<TreeNode>();
        IndexList1 = FindIndex(treeView1.Nodes, IndexList1);
        indx1 = IndexList1[0].Index;

        foreach (TreeNode node1 in nodes1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < actions1.Count; i++)
            {
                List_type1.Add(new Tuple<int, List<string>>(i, new List<string>()));
                TreeNode str1 = node1.Nodes[indx1].Nodes[i];
                string TypeAction1 = actions1[i].Attributes["type"].Value;
                string NameAction1 = actions1[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
                List_type1[i].Item1.Equals(TypeAction1);
                List_type1[i].Item2.Add(NameAction1);
            }
        }
```

Where `nodes1` is a `TreeNodeCollection` and `FindIndex` find the number of nodes in `TreeNodes`.

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: it is in the line: `List_type1[i].Item1.Equals(TypeAction1);`

Comment: And what does the `FindIndex` do? is this your custom method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it could be as the following:

```
        List<Tuple<int, List<string>, List<string>>> List_type1 = new List<Tuple<int, List<string>, List<string>>>();
        foreach (TreeNode node1 in nodes1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < actions1.Count; i++)
            {
                List_type1.Add(new Tuple<int, List<string>, List<string>>(i, new List<string>(), new List<string>()));
                TreeNode str1 = node1.Nodes[indx1].Nodes[i];
                list1.Add(str1);
                string TypeAction1 = actions1[i].Attributes["type"].Value;
                string NameAction1 = actions1[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
                List_type1[i].Item2.Add(TypeAction1);
                List_type1[i].Item3.Add(NameAction1);
            }
        }
```

Or another way which would be useful too is creating an `array`:

```
        string[,] Match_result = new string[list1.Count, 2];
        foreach (TreeNode node1 in nodes1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < actions1.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode str1 = node1.Nodes[indx1].Nodes[i];
                list1.Add(str1);
                string TypeAction1 = actions1[i].Attributes["type"].Value;
                string NameAction1 = actions1[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
                Match_result[i, 0] = TypeAction1;
                Match_result[i, 1] = NameAction1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In this answer, you do not even need to have `List<string>` since it always only have one element... somemore, you will have `actions.Count * nodes1.Count` number of items in your list...

Answer (score 1):

At the moment when you do this

```
List_type1[i].Item1.Equals(TypeAction1);
```

List is empty. You should add new Tuple and only then compare. But your comparision is useless? because of don't use result of it.

Another way is initialize List before loop.

Or maybe you mix up two lines of code and you mean this:

```
List_type1[i].Item2.Add(NameAction1);
List_type1[i].Item1.Equals(TypeAction1);
```

But anyway second line of code means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the line :

```
List_type1[i].Item1.Equals(TypeAction1);
```

You call an object by its index, but the list is empty.